# When does struct didSet get triggered with multiple mutating variables?

Tags: swift

I have a struct with a mutating function that mutates multiple variables. I am under the assumption the struct gets changed on every variable change, since it is a value type. However, the didSet of the struct is only called once when the mutating func is called. Can someone explain to me how the didSet gets triggered?

```
struct MutatingStruct {
    var intValue = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("int value didSet")
        }
    }
    var stringValue = "" {
        didSet {
            print("string value didSet")
        }
    }

    mutating func setValues() {
        intValue += 1
        mutateTimesTwo()
    }

    private mutating func mutateTimesTwo() {
        stringValue += "a"
    }
}
class SomeClass {
    var mutatingStruct = MutatingStruct() {
        didSet {
            print("mutatingStruct didSet")
        }
    }

    func setHelpStruct() {
        mutatingStruct.setValues()
    }
}

let someClass = SomeClass()
someClass.setHelpStruct()
```

Expected Output:

```
int value didSet
mutatingStruct didSet
string value didSet
mutatingStruct didSet
```

Actual Output:

```
int value didSet
string value didSet
mutatingStruct didSet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! Structs are value type. So they get copied even on change!

So imagine of this:

- New instance initialized with the copied values of the original struct.
- `intValue` gets it's new value (in copied instance)
- `stringValue` gets it's new value (in copied instance)
- `mutatingStruct` (the original) gets it's new value (replaced with the *modified copied instance*)

value types considered as a **single value**, even they have multiple attributes. So they get change only after returning from a `mutating func`. So bullet 1 and 2 will change the cloned instance but bullet 3 (the last one) is changing the original struct.

Remember that Swift is very smarter than that and it will **NOT!** copy everything over and over (behind the scene). But acts in the way to seems like that. The actual copy operation will perform ONLY if you have access to the previous and new version of the same value type and one of them changed.

In Swift (behind the scene), value types are reference types that acting like a primitive type from the caller perspective!

You can read comments of this answer for more clarifying.

Comment: When does (the original) struct get its new value? Why doesn't it replace the modified copied instance immediately after the intValue is changed?

Comment: Because you didn't return from the *mutating func* yet.

Comment: So on every mutating func return the original struct gets its new value? However the setValues() func calls another mutating func which returns before the setValues() func is returned. Shouldn't the original struct get a new value then?

Comment: Yes it should and it will! but not on the original, on the newly cloned instance!

Comment: OH wow, okay. So just to clarify -- In every mutating func, if a variable gets changed, a copied instance of the struct is created. This newly copied instance is then set to the original at the return. So, if a newly copied instance calls another mutating func, the newly copied instance will be set to the return of that mutated func return.

Comment: Something logically like that. But remember swift is very smarter than that and it will **NOT!** copy everything over and over (behind the scene). But acts in the way to seems like that. The actual copy operation will perform **ONLY** if you have access to the previous and new version of the same value type and one of them changed.

Comment: The comments discussion answered my question -- Please edit your answer to reflect this discussion and I can award you the accepted answer!

Comment: Ok done. check it out and feel free to ask any further question